# DATE in a between dynamic

Tags: mysql, date, dynamic

I need to build an SQL query which does the following

```
SELECT  pi.desc,
    pa.nameAddress,
    pi.ref,
    pi.descItem,
    pi.quantity,
    pi.totalDF,
    pi.code,
    pi.codeBL,
    cl.dateShip,    po.dtValidated,     po.supervisorDate,  DATEDIFF(po.supervisorDate, po.dtValidated) AS 'diffValidSupervisor',   DATEDIFF(cl.dtlivr, po.supervisorDate) AS 'diffExpeValid',  year(cl.dtlivr),    month(cl.dtlivr) FROM
    new.proforma_item pi
        INNER JOIN
    old.cdestk_lig cl ON pi.codeCde = cl.codcde INNER JOIN new.proforma po ON po.idProforma = pi.idProforma Inner JOIN new.proforma_address pa ON po.idProforma = pa.idProforma GROUP BY pi.desc, pi.ref, pi.descItem, pi.code, pi.codeBL, cl.dateShip, po.dtValidated, po.supervisorDate, month(cl.dateShip), po.dateInvoice HAVING (po.dateInvoice between '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31')
```

But each year I have to review this request to change the year. I want to make this dynamic, because change this manually is just crazy in our architecture.

The best of all is:

Say we are the `15 June 2015`. I would like a between clause that covers the period:

> 2015-01-01 to 2015-05-31

In finite I need a between which take the first day of the current year and last day of last month.

**EDIT**

When we are in Januray, we have to work on the full passed year, not the current month. (January will be treated next month)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to construct the first day of the year and [`LAST_DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) to get the last day of the previous month.

```
po.dateInvoice between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-01-01') AND LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

- [SQL fiddle for the current date](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/7933)
- [SQL fiddle for January 2015](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/7931) (Showing all of 2014)

Comment: @Hooli The accepted answer is unnecessarily complicated. Please give this solution a try instead.

Comment: I already upvote your answer, but i'll give a try to your answer as well

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels my bad I did not notice your `date_format` trick and this is better than mine !  `+1`

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get the first day of the current year using concat function and for getting the last day of the previous month is also straight forward something as

```
mysql> select 
concat(year(curdate()),'-01-01') as fday, 
last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month) as lday ;
+------------+------------+
| fday       | lday       |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-05-31 |
+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in the where clause you just need to replace the hardcoded part with the above date ranges.

```
HAVING 
(
  po.dateInvoice between 
  concat(year(curdate()),'-01-01') AND 
  last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month)
)
```

The above works but still there might be a logical issue, what if we are at January now, so as per the logic it will get the first day of the year and then last day of the previous month and its Dec 31st previous year and having clause will fail, so may be need an extra condition something while getting the last day as

```
case 
  when month(curdate()) = 1 then concat(year(curdate()),'-01-31') 
  else last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month) 
end
```

So when you are in January it will get record from 1st Jan till 31st

UPDATE:

> When we are in Januray, we have to work on the full passed year, not
>   the current month. (January will be treated next month)

The logic could be applied as

```
HAVING 
(
  po.dateInvoice between 
   case 
   when 
    month(curdate()) = 1 then concat(year(curdate())-1,'-01-01') else concat(year(curdate()),'-01-01')
   end
  AND
   case 
   when
    month(curdate()) = 1 then concat(year(curdate())-1,'-12-31') else  last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month)
   end
)
```

Comment: Why use `date_format()`? `last_day()` returns a date, you don't need to parse it again.

Comment: It worked but I still might have an logical issue. See the update.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Hum, good point, but if we are in january we have to work on the whole 2014 year not the current month. (Invoice purpose we bill the passed month)

Comment: So it will return data from last year jan till dec end ?

Comment: If we are in january it will return jan to dec of the past year, and only when we are in february we will work on January of the new year, so yes.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. You simply take the first day of the year of last month. The case is a complete overkill.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels read the statement why there is a case statement and if you have a better answer it instead of complaining about someone's answer !

Comment: @Hooli there was a small type which I corrected now in the answer.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I already have posted [a better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069263/date-in-a-between-dynamic/#31069496). Please take a look.

Comment: And your answer does not satisfy the condition on which the range should be built up on. Go through the comment and why we need the case statement and the update from OP.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty **It does so!** Consider that the current date is the 22th of January, the statement `DATE_FORMAT("2015-01-22" - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-01-01')` will yield "2014-01-01". Doing `- INTERVAL 1 MONTH` in the first day field is the key and makes the whole `CASE` unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think these SQL help to you.

```
SELECT  pi.desc,
    pa.nameAddress,
    pi.ref,
    pi.descItem,
    pi.quantity,
    pi.totalDF,
    pi.code,
    pi.codeBL,
    cl.dateShip,    po.dtValidated,     po.supervisorDate,  DATEDIFF(po.supervisorDate, po.dtValidated) AS 'diffValidSupervisor',   
    DATEDIFF(cl.dtlivr, po.supervisorDate) AS 'diffExpeValid',  year(cl.dtlivr),    month(cl.dtlivr) FROM
    new.proforma_item pi
        INNER JOIN
    old.cdestk_lig cl ON pi.codeCde = cl.codcde INNER JOIN new.proforma po ON po.idProforma = pi.idProforma 
    Inner JOIN new.proforma_address pa ON po.idProforma = pa.idProforma GROUP BY pi.desc, pi.ref, pi.descItem, pi.code, pi.codeBL, cl.dateShip, 
    po.dtValidated, po.supervisorDate, month(cl.dateShip), po.dateInvoice 
    HAVING (po.dateInvoice between CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-01-01') AND   last_day(curdate()-interval 1 month))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to the year?

Comment: But he doesn't want the second date to always be `12-31`. It's supposed to be the last day of the month before now.

Comment: @Barmar, this answer can help someone else to make their queries dynamic, it's not answer my second part, but it's a nice answwer anyway :)